# CSS Window Width Problem

Tags: css

Ok so someone advised me to post this question here, it may sound stupid and trivial to many of you but help a brotha out.

[www.gsprating.com](http://www.gsprating.com)

If you collapse the window to about 1200px wide you will notice that you can still scroll to the right, but not to the left. I need the side images to be fluid with the browser window.

If you want to help, please look at the source and style.css and tell me why!!! and how I can fix this problem.

```
#left{
   background:transparent url(/images/promos/grif_left.png) no-repeat scroll center top;
   height:1080px;
   left:-461px;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   width:461px;
}

#right{
   background:transparent url(/images/promos/grif_right.png) no-repeat scroll center top;
   height:1080px;
   left:1000px;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   width:381px;
}
```

Comment: Why does left have negative 461 pixels?

Comment: I am currently on a 1024X768 screen and the issue I have is that the "Follow GSP" div is overwriting the content on the page. But I can still scroll the images left or right. I get this with Firefox. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Aidanc the -461 places the left image 461px to the left of the wrapper. As well as the 1000px places the right image 1000px to the right of the wrapper

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having. Could you try to explain it in a very detailed way (use images to help, if you must)? You said "If you collapse the window to about 1200px wide you will notice that you can still scroll to the right" - this is not the case; I can never horizontally scroll, no matter how wide or narrow my window is. I tested in Firefox, amongst other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the problem exactly, I was never able to see scrollbars.

But I did find a problem, you have CSS styles that are setting the body's overflow to hidden.

Here's 
http://www.gsprating.com/wp-content/w3tc/min/1f1244/default.include.1061365648.css

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    color: #161514;
    font-family: Arial,Georgia,Tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* change this to see scrollbar */
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I used overflow-x: hidden to hide the scrollbars so my users don't see it. But my question is how can I stop it from wanting to scroll?

Comment: Again, I didn't see any scrolling anywhere, please add more detailed steps to reproduce or get a screenshot of what you are seeing, a video capture would be even better (jing.com has a free tool to do video capture)